# Hiding Property in HttpPost not in HttpGet

Tags: c#, swagger

I am using swagger for web api documentation , where i need to hide one of my  property in the model (ex:in student model "createdatetime" is my property which is to be hided ) but i should hide it only in HttpPost not in HttpGet. Is there any option like hiding the property only in the post method but not in get method. please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorator for example  `@api.hide`,more details you can 
Check out [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec)
,it list each version for each language,you can dive deep into it,and check out the test case about how to use!
Also,you can check out [this](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documenting.html),there are specification and full example to go.

Comment: I am sorry. I previously forgot to tag the question under c#. All my code is in c#. Can you tell me how to do it in C#?

Comment: you can find what you want from the link i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

For hiding a property in Swagger , we need to take "hidden" property in PropInfo class and then in "TryToAddModels" class change the hidden property  based on the requirement.